# SQL left join with filter not using the filter

Tags: sql, left-join

In this code snippet:

```
proc sql;

    create table test3 (id numeric (10));
    create table test4 (id numeric (10));
    quit;


    proc sql;
    insert into test3 (id) values (1);
    insert into test3 (id) values (2);
    insert into test3 (id) values (2);

    insert into test4 (id) values (1);
    insert into test4 (id) values (2);

    create table test5 as 
    select * from test3 left join test4 on test3.id = test4.id 

    and test3.id<> 2 and test4.id <> 2;

    quit;
```

I am trying to get all rows from test3 even if there are no matching rows on test4, provided that the value of id column <>2 in test3 and test4....a.k.a in the final output, I don't want the id = 2 record, not even once.

But the above join is giving:

```
1
2
2
```

As if the <> 2 filter is not there at all. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
create table test5 as 
select * from test3 left join test4 on test3.id = test4.id 

WHERE test3.id<> 2 and test4.id <> 2;
```

Your join clause includes an `and` which is likely creating a union. Change to `where`.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but also in the WHERE, if I use OR instead of AND, it gives same (desired) result. Why is that?

Comment: In your example data, the combination of joining on test3.id=test4.id and then filtering by test3.id<>2 OR test4.id<>2 ...is equivalent to joining and using AND criteria. For your example, it doesn't matter.  Same reason Gordon's answer works, and is arguably a more direct answer to your question.

Comment: Said another way, `left join on test3.id=test4.id` combined with `where test3.id <> 2` insures no test3.id=2 records will be selected, which then automatically means no test4.id=2 records will be included either, because test3 is the primarily/left join table.

Comment: Thanks. By that logic in your answer, do we need test4.id <> 2? If we say test3.id <>2 , that should do it right? I tried and it worked but am not confident if it is jsut working for this particular data set.

Comment: Given your example data, the `test4.id <> 2` clause in my answer is redundant. As to if it's required depends on what you are trying to do in the larger context. It is probably more important you understand _why_ it works. Again, @Gordon's answer is also highly relevant.

Answer (score 2):

This is the query in question:

```
select *
from test3 left join
     test4
     on test3.id = test4.id and
        test3.id <> 2 and test4.id <> 2;
```

A `left join` keeps all rows from the first table and any matching rows from the second.  If there are no matching rows for a given row in the first table, then the row is kept.

In other words, when you do a `left join`, a filter in the `on` clause on the first table has no effect.  You should move this condition to a `where` clause:

```
select *
from test3 left join
     test4
     on test3.id = test4.id and
        test4.id <> 2
where test3.id <> 2;
```